# Simple matlab while loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I am trying to figure out how to create a loop in matlab that can repeat a statement but increase/decrease the numbers in the statement each time.

So, for example, I want to repeat the statement -

```
Elset, elset="element 1", instance="simple plate-1" 150000,
```

Many times over so but increasing the element numbers so that it starts to come together like this -

```
Elset, elset="element 1", instance="simple plate-1" 150000,
Elset, elset="element 2", instance="simple plate-1" 149999,
Elset, elset="element 3", instance="simple plate-1" 149998,
Elset, elset="element 4", instance="simple plate-1" 149997,
Elset, elset="element 5", instance="simple plate-1" 149996,
Elset, elset="element 6", instance="simple plate-1"
```

This feel as though it should be very simple but I havent figured it out yet. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
lineStr = 'Elset, elset="element %d", instance="simple plate-1" %d,\n'

for i = 0 : 150000 - 1
    fprintf(1, lineStr, i, 150000 - i);
end
```